# How can I clip everything outside of a border in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a form with the top edges rounded in WPF. I have successfully done that part, although I have a canvas as a header on the form and the background image inside of it covers the rounded edges on my border. Is there a way to clip the edges from this canvas if it goes outside of the border? I tried sending the border to the back and set each element to clip although that does not work. If I set the border to the front then the border just sits on top. Can anyone offer some assistance?

Here is how I am creating the form with rounded corners-

```
<Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Height="645" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="mainBorder" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="867" CornerRadius="10, 10, 0, 0" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" UseLayoutRounding="False" ClipToBounds="False" Background="{StaticResource FormGradient}">
            <Canvas Height="43" Name="canvas1" Width="794" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,320">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WPFPROJECT;component/Images/canvas-nav-bar.png" Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,106,92" ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
                </Canvas.Background>
                <Rectangle Canvas.Left="-36.5" Canvas.Top="-25" Height="11" Name="headercanvasFooter" Stroke="{x:Null}" Width="867" Fill="White"></Rectangle>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
        <Canvas Height="118" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="headerCanvas" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="867" ClipToBounds="True" DataContext="{Binding}" IsItemsHost="False">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WPFPROJECT;component/Images/Ps-HeaderSlice.png" Stretch="Fill" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,27,158" ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
            </Canvas.Background>
            <Image Canvas.Left="698" Canvas.Top="6" Height="64" Name="headerLogo" Stretch="None" Width="163" Source="/WPFPROJECT;component/Images/WPFPROJECTImage.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" StretchDirection="Both" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Visible" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" UseLayoutRounding="True" IsManipulationEnabled="False" ClipToBounds="False" />
        </Canvas>
```

Comment: What effect does it have when you set ClipToBounds to true?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpacityMask on your inner Canvas to make the edges appear transparent

```
<Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="20" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Canvas Background="Red" Width="50" Height="50" Opacity="0.5">
        <Canvas.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" 
                            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=border}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=border}"/>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Canvas.OpacityMask>
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```